# How to run the C# program in ubuntu 14.04 using VS code?

Tags: c#

I have installed VS code and .Net core in my ubuntu 14.04. I have written a C# program and now I want  to run it. How to run it or is there any compiler I need to install?

Answer (score 4):

install .NET Core, and try `dotnet run`: https://www.microsoft.com/net/core#ubuntu